# Issue after provider changed serveur/db

Tags: webserver

I have now a new issue with one of my CiviCRM website.

My provider (Infomaniak) decided to move to a new server.

All my Joomla website works well but I have now a trouble with CiviCRM.

When I start it I get this :

```
XML data could not be loaded. Make sure you specified the correct path.
Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   JAdministrator->dispatch()  JROOT/administrator/index.php:46
2   JError::raiseError()    JROOT/administrator/includes/application.php:164
3   JError::raise() JROOT/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
```

Could someone help me ?

Thanks a lot for your answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete /media/civicrm/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini file.

This will fix the issue.

This is clearly mentioned in Step 9 in the docs - http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location . Make sure you (your provider) follow these instructions when moving CiviCRM to new server/location